# Xamarin.iOS MapKit: Looking for an equivalent to Android.Gms.Maps.Model.GroundOverlay

Tags: ios, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mapkit

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app that uses Google Maps and adds annotations to it, using custom renderer. We want the annotation to resize when the user zooms in or out. In Android this can achieved by using the GroundOverlay class, however I haven't found an equivalent for iOS.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Also posted on Xamarin forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92527/ios-mapkit-looking-for-an-equivalent-to-android-gms-maps-model-groundoverlay

Comment: t's easy. You need to implement Infowindow with custom UIView for marker and handle zoom in/out action, if zoomed IN then change infowindow UIView size and vice versa for zoom OUT.

Comment: Thank you @XTL, does this work with MKMapView or do I have to add the Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps package?

Comment: it can be done on both,but each of them have different API(logic is the same)

Comment: @XTL, do you have any samples for that? can we follow up via chat?

Comment: i will provide sample soon.

Comment: i have made on the fly example. Is this you want : https://giphy.com/gifs/xUA7b1HPLdSEJkWOuA ?

Comment: Thank you, @XTL! Can you please share the source code with me as well?

Comment: @mrubin hi there, so about this one you asked ? I can share code tomorrow.